# How to include different blade template view in if-else clause in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have gone through [Laravel Blade tutorial](http://laravel.com/docs/templates). I have using it in my project. But I want to add different blade template views on basis of Item selected in drop-down list.

**Example:-** I have one create Question.blade.php page.

**Question.blade.php**

```
<div class="question_type">
<?php $question_type= array('--' => '--- Select Question Type ---') 
+QuestionType::lists('name', 'id') ?>
{{ Form::select('question_type', $question_type,'--' ,array('id'=>'question_type','class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

Now I want to add different type of views on basis of option selected in Question_Type drop-down. I am trying to do it in Java Script.

**Java Script Code:-**

```
 function addQuestion() 
 {
   var question_type=$("#question_type").val();

   switch (question_type) 
   {
    case 1:
    $("#Questions").load("questions/type1.blade.php");
    case 2:
    $("#Questions").load("questions/type2.blade.php");
    default:
    $("#Questions").load("questions/default_type.blade.php");
  }
}
```

But I am getting error **localhost/mywebsite/question/questions/type1.blade.php 404 (Not Found)**

Is there any solution to include blade view using @if @else or @switch on basis of dropdown selected item's value?

My Pseudo Code:-

```
@if {{question_type.selected.val='1'}}
@include(question.type1);
@elseif {{question_type.selected.val='2'}}
@include(question.type2);
@else
@include(question.default_type);
@endif
```

Comment: `$.load("questions/type1.blade.php");` expects the url (that returns a view), not the path to the view file

Comment: Can I use PHP for it?

Comment: you cannot visit blade in js, and you cannot run js in {{}} too

Comment: is there any way to do it? I mean I don't want to write whole HTML code in JavaScript page to append it. It dont like cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making a request to laravel, you need to have a [route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) with a method associated with it (whether its a simple closure as in their hello world examples or a method inside of a [controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) class).

Inside of *that* method is where you can perform your logic on which view to return:

```
if($someCondition) {
    return View::make('template1');
} else {
    return View::make('template2');
}
```

In your javascript, send your `question_type` along as a parameter in the AJAX request.  Then in your controller method you can make your decision:

```
$("#Questions").load("questions/type", "question_type="+question_type);
```

Your route:

```
Route::get('questions/type', function() {
    switch(Input::get('question_type')) {
        case 1:
            return View::make("questions/type1.blade.php");
        case 2:
            return View::make("questions/type2.blade.php");
        default:
            return View::make("questions/default_type.blade.php");
    }
});
```

Your call to `jQuery.load()` will implicitly set the contents of the DOM element with ID Questions equal to the entire output of the request (whatever is contained in the returned view).  From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Comment: Thanks for reply..can I do it in JavaScript? I mean how can I load different type of sub-view without page refresh on Drop-Down on change event? My problem will be solved if I know how Laravel converts @include(blade_sub_view) in to HTML code. ....Still struggling...

Comment: Yes, you can do it with javascript, but you need to direct your AJAX request to a _laravel route_.  You cannot request the blade template directly.

Comment: yup..Right approach...Thanks bro....  :)  but AJAX will return whole page or it will return sub-view .That I can append in my Question_form?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The call to .load should automatically take the output of the request and set the contents of `$('#Questions')` to it.

Comment: Hats off man..Your code is working.. 
But `$("#Questions").load("questions/type", "question_type="+question_type);` is replacing my whole page.Can I append the HTML code returned by AJAX?

Comment: Finally I did it :)     But is it good to send AJAX request to server to display div in a form? I mean JQuery or Java Script can't do it?